# Train my model in tensorflow 2 checkpoint is expected to be an object-based checkpoint

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm creating a new model following this tutorial https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html but when i try to training the model, i execute the following sentence:

```
python model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=models/my_ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn --pipeline_config_path=models/my_ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn/pipeline.config
```

And this is the output:

```
    2020-10-21 14:01:05.982155: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2020-10-21 14:01:06.000363: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x7fbb44f076b0 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-10-21 14:01:06.000386: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
WARNING:tensorflow:There are non-GPU devices in `tf.distribute.Strategy`, not using nccl allreduce.
W1021 14:01:06.001132 4568120768 cross_device_ops.py:1202] There are non-GPU devices in `tf.distribute.Strategy`, not using nccl allreduce.
INFO:tensorflow:Using MirroredStrategy with devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',)
I1021 14:01:06.001378 4568120768 mirrored_strategy.py:341] Using MirroredStrategy with devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',)
INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting train_steps: 10000
I1021 14:01:06.005095 4568120768 config_util.py:552] Maybe overwriting train_steps: 10000
INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting use_bfloat16: False
I1021 14:01:06.005259 4568120768 config_util.py:552] Maybe overwriting use_bfloat16: False
INFO:tensorflow:Reading unweighted datasets: ['/Users/jose/Desktop/Tensorflow/workspace/training_demo/annotations/train.record']
I1021 14:01:06.044616 4568120768 dataset_builder.py:148] Reading unweighted datasets: ['/Users/jose/Desktop/Tensorflow/workspace/training_demo/annotations/train.record']
INFO:tensorflow:Reading record datasets for input file: ['/Users/jose/Desktop/Tensorflow/workspace/training_demo/annotations/train.record']
I1021 14:01:06.045146 4568120768 dataset_builder.py:77] Reading record datasets for input file: ['/Users/jose/Desktop/Tensorflow/workspace/training_demo/annotations/train.record']
INFO:tensorflow:Number of filenames to read: 1
I1021 14:01:06.045268 4568120768 dataset_builder.py:78] Number of filenames to read: 1
WARNING:tensorflow:num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input file shards.
W1021 14:01:06.045435 4568120768 dataset_builder.py:85] num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input file shards.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /opt/anaconda3/envs/ComputerVision/lib/python3.8/site-packages/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:99: parallel_interleave (from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.interleave_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.interleave(map_func, cycle_length, block_length, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)` instead. If sloppy execution is desired, use `tf.data.Options.experimental_deterministic`.
W1021 14:01:06.047674 4568120768 deprecation.py:317] From /opt/anaconda3/envs/ComputerVision/lib/python3.8/site-packages/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:99: parallel_interleave (from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.interleave_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.interleave(map_func, cycle_length, block_length, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)` instead. If sloppy execution is desired, use `tf.data.Options.experimental_deterministic`.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /opt/anaconda3/envs/ComputerVision/lib/python3.8/site-packages/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:221: DatasetV1.map_with_legacy_function (from tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.map()
W1021 14:01:06.087840 4568120768 deprecation.py:317] From /opt/anaconda3/envs/ComputerVision/lib/python3.8/site-packages/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:221: DatasetV1.map_with_legacy_function (from tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.map()
WARNING:tensorflow:From /opt/anaconda3/envs/ComputerVision/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201: sparse_to_dense (from tensorflow.python.ops.sparse_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Create a `tf.sparse.SparseTensor` and use `tf.sparse.to_dense` instead.
W1021 14:01:12.571774 4568120768 deprecation.py:317] From /opt/anaconda3/envs/ComputerVision/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201: sparse_to_dense (from tensorflow.python.ops.sparse_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Create a `tf.sparse.SparseTensor` and use `tf.sparse.to_dense` instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /opt/anaconda3/envs/ComputerVision/lib/python3.8/site-packages/object_detection/inputs.py:262: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.cast` instead.
W1021 14:01:15.363219 4568120768 deprecation.py:317] From /opt/anaconda3/envs/ComputerVision/lib/python3.8/site-packages/object_detection/inputs.py:262: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.cast` instead.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model_main_tf2.py", line 113, in <module>
    tf.compat.v1.app.run()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/ComputerVision/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/ComputerVision/lib/python3.8/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 300, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/ComputerVision/lib/python3.8/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "model_main_tf2.py", line 104, in main
    model_lib_v2.train_loop(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/ComputerVision/lib/python3.8/site-packages/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py", line 564, in train_loop
    load_fine_tune_checkpoint(detection_model,
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/ComputerVision/lib/python3.8/site-packages/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py", line 346, in load_fine_tune_checkpoint
    raise IOError('Checkpoint is expected to be an object-based checkpoint.')
OSError: Checkpoint is expected to be an object-based checkpoint.
```

I dont know why raise the following error Checkpoint is expected to be an object-based checkpoint. if i have followed the tutorial step by step. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 6):

The logs sound like the `fine_tune_checkpoint` property is pointing to an invalid checkpoint location:

`OSError: Checkpoint is expected to be an object-based checkpoint.`

Check the `fine_tune_checkpoint` property in your pipeline.config file, located at: `models/my_ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn/pipeline.config`

In the example you link to, it is set as:

`fine_tune_checkpoint: "pre-trained-models/ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_640x640_coco17_tpu-8/checkpoint/ckpt-0"`

Do you have that set to a valid checkpoint directory?

You'll want a directory, typically named `checkpoint`, which has at least 3 valid checkpoint files: `checkpoint`, `ckpt-0.index`, and `ckpt-0.data-00000-of-00001`. You link to a given checkpoint with it's id: e.g. `ckpt-0`.

See also [TensorFlow 2 Detection Model Zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md) if you need to download the pre-trained model.

The example you linked to used `SSD ResNet50 V1 FPN 640x640`.

Comment: I changed it to detection and I have all those files. But it is still the same error!

Comment: This worked for me (or, at least, I got a new error, and we all know that is progress), but it is worth emphasizing: you won't have a file called `checkpoint/ckpt-0` but that is what you need to use in the config to make it work. Not intuitive at all, but that's how it works :shrug:

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `fine_tune_checkpoint_type` to `"detection"`.

Comment: i think there is any issue with your config file
please search for config file
fine_tune_checkpoint: "D:/faster_rcnn_resnet101_v1_800x1333_coco17_gpu-8/checkpoint/ckpt-0" 
and this value something like above line

also if there is a chance to share your config data would be more helpful

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issue with your config file. Please search for the config file `fine_tune_checkpoint`:

```
D:/faster_rcnn_resnet101_v1_800x1333_coco17_gpu-8/checkpoint/ckpt-0
```

and this value, something like the line above.

Also if there is a chance to share your config data, it would be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I exactly had the same problem as you had, and the suggestions above didn't work either for me.

Finally what I realized is that `fine_tune_checkpoint` was expecting a path without `.index` extension. However the file you copied from the model zoo contains `.index` extension, if you have directly copied the path from it then most probabaly this `.index` extension would stay there, so this resulted the error.

For me changing the `fine_tune_checkpoint`, from `...checkpoint/ckpt-0.index` to `...checkpoint/ckpt-0` has corrected the issue.

Answer (score 0):

i think you just need to change the `fine_tune_checkpoint` ckpt-0.index to `ckpt-0`